# Getting a spinner working properly in Grails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I'm trying to get a `spinner` working properly in my grails app.  The way I understand it, is it should work out of the box while waiting for an action to complete.  It is not doing this.

I was able to get a spinner working based on some suggestions I found from google, and modified this solution: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/spinner-or-progress-indicator-td1363802.html , however this seems rather hacky to me, and not an optimal solution.

Which indicated I needed the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function showSpinner() {
          document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'inline';
          document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
      }

      function hideSpinner() {
          document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
      }

      function showError(e) {
          var errorDiv = document.getElementById('error')
          errorDiv.innerHTML = '<ul><li>'
                   + e.responseText + '</li></ul>';
          errorDiv.style.display = 'block';
      }
    </script>
```

Which I employed with a grails button as such:

```
<g:submitToRemote value="Validate Address"
url="[action: 'standardizedList', controller: 'address']"
update="addressList" after="showSpinner();" onSuccess="hideSpinner()"
class="btn btn-primary"/><br>

<img id="spinner" style="display:none;"
 src="${createLinkTo(dir: 'images', file: 'spinner.gif')}"
 alt="Spinner"/>
```

Now I put the javascript snippet into `/layouts/main.gsp`, but it appears I have to add the spinner image into each page where I want it, and if I put it in the `div` where I want it to show, it will be overwritten when the action completes and updates the `div` so I have to add the `spinner` in the page that is responding as well as inside the response body.

When I look at the given `main.gsp` it has the following code in it:

```
<div id="spinner" class="spinner" style="display:none;">
<g:message code="spinner.alt" default="Loading&hellip;"/>
</div>
```

furthermore, found inside the `web-app/js/` directory there is a file `application.js` which contains the code that I saw frequently which is supposed to add the spinner.

```
if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
(function($) {
    $('#spinner').ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).fadeIn();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

}

Now I have several places where I believe actions may cause a delay, and I want the spinner to tell the user it's working.  So my question is two fold: 1) Am I understanding how it is supposed to be working?  If so, 2) how can I make the out of the box code work properly?

Comment: try after="showSpinner();" to before="showSpinner();"

Comment: I may not have been horribly clear here, that code works, but I want every ajax request to show a spinner without using the `after` and `onsuccess`.  Interestingly enough I used `after` because when I used before the only thing it would do is show the spinner, the action would never even call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I do it: make sure the following JavaScript is included in every page, e.g. by putting it in a .js file which is included in the layout:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var showSpinner = function() {
        $("#spinner").fadeIn('fast');
    };

    // Global handlers for AJAX events
    $(document)
        .on("ajaxSend", showSpinner)
        .on("ajaxStop", function() {
            $("#spinner").fadeOut('fast');
        })
        .on("ajaxError", function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
            $("#spinner").hide();                
        });
});
```

The functions above will be called every time an AJAX request is stopped, started, or returns with an error. Also include the following in the layout:

```
<div id="spinner" style="display:none;">
    <g:img uri="/images/spinner.gif" alt="Loading..."/>
</div>
```

This is the content which is shown/hidden when an AJAX request starts/stops. In my case I apply the following styles, so that the spinner is shown in the center of the screen on top of any other content:

```
#spinner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px; // half width of the spinner gif
  margin-top: -50px; // half height of the spinner gif
  z-index: 5000;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the spinner not being removed on one of my ajax calls, have you seen this behaviour previously any quick tips on fixing it?

Comment: It turns out the problem I was having with the spinner staying was because I was rendering a template which had a div called spinner in it already, which meant there were two (one which had the active spinner in it, and the empty one from the rendered template), so when the script was trying to turn it off it couldn't remove the correct one.